# How to get rid of the datatype in json response from flask/mongoengine

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, mongoengine

I'm developing an application backend using flask

When I return responses, some datatypes are included in it along with the value. Here is a sample code of some logic to return a document value

```py
def single_user(user_id):
    user = users.read(user_id)
    if user:
        return {
            'success': True,
            'user': user,
        }, 200
    return {
        'success': False,
        'message': 'User not found',
    }, 404
```

My user model is as such

```py
from datetime import datetime

import mongoengine as me


class User(me.Document):
    phone = me.StringField()
    email = me.EmailField()
    password = me.StringField()
    accountType = me.StringField()
    createdAt = me.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    updatedAt = me.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    profil = me.EmbeddedDocumentField(Profil)

    meta = {
        'collection': 'users',
        'strict': False,
    }
```

And here is a sample output of the response

```
{
    "success": true,
    "user": {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5dc968e2e50cca5af0ba50cc"
        },
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": 1573491186501
        },
        "profil": {
            "checked": false,
            "followerList": [
                {
                    "$oid": "5dc96268788964480d6a2a8a"
                }
            ],
            "followingList": [],
            "playpoint": 15
        },
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": 1573491186501
        }
    }
}
```

Which is fine and all, but is there a way to get rid of the "$oid" and "$date" from the output and just get the value?

I think it's a python thing because when I try serving those datas from a nodejs equivalent backend, I just have the values in the "id", "createdAt" and "updatedAt".

**Edit:** Here would be the desired output

```
{
    "success": true,
    "user": {
        "_id": "5dc968e2e50cca5af0ba50cc",
        "createdAt": 1573491186501,
        "profil": {
            "checked": false,
            "followerList": [
                "5dc96268788964480d6a2a8a"
            ],
            "followingList": [],
            "playpoint": 15
        },
        "updatedAt": 1573491186501
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has to do with the way MongoEngine works. That is what's returning those fields. Only way to fix it is to map the fields by yourself.

```
def single_user(user_id):
    user = users.read(user_id)
    if user:
        mappedUser = {
            '_id': user['_id']['$oid'],
            'createdAt': user['createdAt']['$date'],
            ...
        }
        return {
            'success': True,
            'user': mappedUser,
        }, 200
    return {
        'success': False,
        'message': 'User not found',
    }, 404
```

Extra tip: Flask-Restplus (additional library) supports "marshaling" of responses, which is basically what you would like to do.

Comment: it looks like it's more from `flask-mongoengine` than only mongoengine, which is using `bson.json_util.py`, function `default(obj, json_options=DEFAULT_JSON_OPTIONS)` at bson/json_util.py at line 728

Comment: I had to do it the hard way, added methods to output mapped objects for each kind of model. but btw, the way I could render the values were like `'_id': str(user.id)`